# Add Data Attribute from Model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to render a html5 data attribute on an HTML tag?  In this case I want to be able to specify a default value for the form input control from the Model class:

```
[AdditionalMetadata("data-default-value", "60")]
```

I'm using the AdditionalMetadata attribute to add the data attribute and value I want, and the TextBoxFor helper to render the input tag.  The problem is that I don't see the data attribute - do I need to do something else to render it?  Is there a better way to do this from the Model class?

Mark

Comment: This may help: http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/asp-net-mvc-add-html5-microdata-to-your-applications-using-metadata-providers/

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see the data attribute"? Where exactly don't you see it?

Comment: It doesn't have general solution, think about custom complex templates, for instance. However, you may think of changing `Object` template in your project such as it will look for additional attributes to render simple Editor or Display templates, or simply change TextBox template accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like the following, depending on what your model looks like (and where you access your property):

Get the target property from the model metadata and then retrieve the "data-" attribute value:

```
string ddv = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(x => x.PropertyName == "myProperty)
             .FirstOrDefault().AdditionalValues["data-default-value"].ToString();
```

Use this information when rendering the property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.MyProperty, new { data-default-value = ddv })
```

**EDIT**: Since C# is sensitive when using the minus symbol ("-"), the best option is to build a `Dictionary<string, object>` when providing such HTML attributes

```
Dictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
htmlAttributes.Add["data-default-value", ddv];
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.MyProperty, htmlAttributes);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - this was the answer I used to build my solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the AdditionalMetadata will not render anything in your markup.

You can see [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/01/30/mvc-3-additionalmetadata-attribute-with-viewbag-to-render-dynamic-ui.aspx), where it shows how to get the value from the attribute, but then you should manually add the data attribute to your input.